# magento2, Child theme in different language

Tags: magento2, multistore, localisation, language

Using below command I have created the csv file for translation. I set the settings for locale in admin panel. After running upgrade and deploy command, I get 404 for all css and js files. In Pub/static I see still files are generated under en_US! What step is missing here?

```
php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases --output="app/design/frontend/Vendor/childtheme/i18n/sv-SE.csv" /app/design/frontend/Vendor/maintheme/
```

Edit:

Running below did not help either :(

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy sv_se
```

Comment: you can just run  command, php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US sv_SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to just run below command,

**You have to replace sv-se to sv_SE**

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy sv_SE

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything under `pub/static` 
Remove var/cache/* var/generation/* var/view_preprocessed/*

Flush cache and issue command

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

you can then reissue

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy sv_SE

Now everything should work as normal. On side note if you're in development you should setup Grunt which makes it real easy to clear and deploy files [further read here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html)